# Sinónimo de "oclocracia"

Tags: solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras

[Oclocracia](https://dle.rae.es/oclocracia) es:

> 1. f. Gobierno de la muchedumbre o de la plebe.

Parece que es poco utilizada. ¿Hay sinónimos más usados?

Comment: Populismo podría ser un familiar de oclocracia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sé que no es lo mismo, pero se me viene a la mente un concepto bastante conocido:

> la **ley de la calle**.

Se refiere al estado social en que el poder está en manos de la masa, aunque, claro, entendemos que "masa" no es cualquier persona sino especialmente los delincuentes.

Con el sentido original de *oclocracia* no creo que encontremos un sinónimo moderno. John Stuart Mill usa el término [**Tiranía de la Mayoría**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiran%C3%ADa_de_la_mayor%C3%ADa) para referirse a una degeneración de la democracia similar a la oclocracia.

Answer (score 0):

Según el diccionario jurídico **Oclocracia**, es el sistema de gobierno opuesto a la aristocracia.

**Oclocracia** del griego ὀχλοκρατία de ὄχλος, óchlos (masas) + κράτος, krátos (gobierno), literalmente el "gobierno de las masas", romanizado "okhlokratía"  (ochlocratia). Para  Maquiavelo la oclocracia es "*el peor de todos los sistemas políticos, el último estado de la degeneración del poder*".

Como sinónimos se pueden utilizar;

- el gobierno de la turba.
- el gobierno de la calle.
- gobierno de la muchedumbre.
- gobierno de la masa.
- gobierno de la multitud.
- gobierno del gentío.
- gobierno de la caterva.
- gobierno de la plebe.
- gobierno de una mafia o con las reglas de esta.
- gobierno del populacho.
- Mobocracia.
- gobierno asambleario.

**P.D.** No confundir con el "gobierno del pueblo", es decir, "la Democracia" pues este, el pueblo, es poseedor de la soberanía y voluntad legitima del poder del estado. La **Oclocracia** llamada también **Mobocracia**, es sin embargo el gobierno de la muchedumbre, de la plebe, de la parte peor de una sociedad que no tiene escrúpulos o miramientos  en intimidar a las autoridades legítimas y en la que existe ya un proceso de deterioro civil y democrático.

Para un mayor desarrollo

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oclocracia

Answer (score 0):

Voy a optar por una expresión algo coloquial: "rodillo"

Como dices, la "oclocracia" se define como el gobierno de la muchedumbre. Yo he utilizado este término al hablar de una perversión de la democracia en la cual una mayoría abrumadora gobierna de facto por el hecho de tener una abrumadora superioridad numérica, dejando al resto de voces en la irrelevancia. Así, el grupo mayoritario "pasa el rodillo" sobre el resto, aplastando cualquier otra opinión.

Sé que esto solamente se podría aplicar a la parte de "muchedumbre" y no tanto a la de la plebe, pero sí me parece un término más familiar que, al fin y al cabo, es lo que se pide...